# Can Kamailio solution interact with other servers?

Tags: voip, kamailio

Im working on a complete server for a VOIP solution.
As per my understanding, Kamailio contains all the functionalities of a Server for providing VOIP services.

I would like to use Lawful intercept server as well for my project.
I would also need to do some provisioning (find out which server to use before actually start using it)

So my questions are
1. Is provisioning possible with Kamailio solution? If not can we add any other server to integrate with  Kamailio
2. What is number of participants that are supported in Voice and Video call for Kamilio?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to create kamailio.cfg to meet your routing needs. Kamailio is more like a framework from this perspective, rather than a full product.

A1. Provisioning can be done in database, or you can tailor Siremis web interface for your particular services.

A2. Kamailio is a signaling proxy. It cannot be a conferencing server, if that was your question. As for user-to-user calls, it doesn't matter their number. The performances of kamailio are about call setups per second, not active calls. Once a call is answered, Kamailio doesn't do anything until call is ended or the session is updated (e.g., call on hold).